# Do banks store the money when we buy stablecoins? Then how is it decentralized?

Tags: ether, usdt, stablecoins, cryptoeconomics, liquidity

I need someone to verify if my understanding is correct.

- When we buy ETH, we swap it in a pool with Stablecoin.
- To trade, it requires a pair of ETH/USD.

What gives a Stablecoin its value?

In the case of USDT, there is the backing of the USD dollar. (Let's ignore crypto collateralized like DAI)

I have three questions:

1. Is stablecoin an entry to the blockchain world?
2. What backs up a non-stablecoin like ETH? Is it the pool of ETH/Stablecoin (Because stablecoin is backed by organizations like Tether in the case of USDT)?
3. When we buy a stablecoin, where the non-blockchain USD goes? Who keeps it? Banks? If banks, how is it decentralized?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token value is something that varies from contract to contract depending on the creator's logic and pricing mechanism, as well as the market supply and demand of the token.

In the case of stablecoins, these are tokens that are coded in such a way as to remain at a constant price with little volatility.

There are many different ways to create a token like this, commonly, a DAO or Organization controls the total supply of the stablecoins through a mint and burn flow. There are other alternatives that rely solely on some coded in math without human the need for human intervention, these special types of stablecoins are called "algorithmic stablecoins"

1. **Q:** *Is stablecoin an entry to the blockchain's world ?*

I wouldn't consider stablecoins an entry to blockchain per se, but like other cryptocurrencies, they are an option you can use to get started interacting with the blockchain. The entries to getting into buying these tokens with fiat currency are known as on-ramps. The importance of a stablecoin is that it is a much steadier store of value than a volatile currency such as ETH.

2. **Q:** *What backs up a non-stablecoin like ETH? Is it the pool of ETH/Stablecoin (Because stablecoin is backed by organizations like Tether in case of USDT) ?*

"non-stablecoin" tokens get their value in the same way many traditional currencies do, by supply and demand and having enough people agree that something is valuable. You can read further [here](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/100314/why-do-bitcoins-have-value.asp) and [here](https://www.coindesk.com/sponsored-content/what-gives-crypto-its-value/).

3. **Q:** *When we buy a stablecoin, where the non-blockchain USD goes? Who keeps it? Banks? If banks, how is it decentralized ?*

Since you mention non-blockchain USD, I'm assuming you are talking about the process of on-ramping by buying a cryptocurrency with fiat money. This step usually takes place on a CEX or a DEX with a KYC process. You can read more about on-ramps [here](https://www.ledger.com/academy/crypto-on-and-off-ramps-say-what) and [here](https://blog.ramp.network/what-is-crypto-ramp). This process may involve centralized authorities, but the cryptocurrencies themselves are still decentralized by nature. (Depending on how the token is implemented, ie. admin, owner roles.) Again, for additional information see [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blockchain/decentralization-in-blockchain/) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JeRq7Gwj5Y).

Comment: Yes, ramping is what i was looking for. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

1. There is no difference between a stable coin and any other ERC20 token. The Value of the stablecoin is given by the funds that the company that issues the stablecoin token claim to have in bank accounts or invested with third parties (usually banks). So USDT or Circle are not decentralized.
2. ETh and other non-stable coins get their value from the belief that people have about its value, if people are willing to pay 4K for 1 ETher, then that is the perceived value but if people lose interest and they are only willing to pay 2K for 1 ether, then that is the value of ether. Nothing other than what people are willing to pay for ETHER set a limit to how high or low it can go.
3. If you open an account on Circle or USDT, and buy from them directly, the money goes to their bank account. If you buy in an exchange you are exchanging your USD by USDT/USDC tokens of another user, and the exchange is an intermediary. None of this is decentralized.